# JSON.stringify and $http request

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JS String, like so:

```
user_fav = "21,16";
```

This has to go thru a function where it becomes a JSON array with an `id` key, like so:

```
{"id":21},{"id":16}
```

And this goes into an $http request:

```
return $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: getUrl('products'),
    params: {
        pageSize: 2000,
        pageNumber: 1,
        "filter": { "q": { "$or": [{"id":21},{"id":16}] } }, // <-- HERE
        sort: []
    }
});
```

Now if I run the above `$http` request everything works fine, but if I convert the String (user_fav) into that JSON and send this to the `$http` request it fires an error. This is my converter:

```
user_fav = "21,16";

var user_fav_to_array = "";
var splitFav = user_fav.split(",");

for (var i = 0; i < splitFav.length; i++) {
    user_fav_to_array += JSON.stringify({ id: parseInt(splitFav[i]) }) + ',';
}

var JSONFavs = user_fav_to_array.substring(0, user_fav_to_array.length - 1);

//Result: JSONFavs => {"id":21},{"id":16}
```

So this gives an error:

```
return $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: getUrl('products'),
    params: {
        pageSize: 2000,
        pageNumber: 1,
        "filter": { "q": { "$or": [JSONFavs] } }, // <-- HERE
        sort: []
    }
});
```

Madame and messier the error is `417 (Critical Exception)`, this is coming from the Backand.com syste

Comment: And the error is...?

Comment: Madame and messier the error is `417 (Critical Exception)`, this is coming from the Backand.com system

Comment: So it means that server is not expecting you to send JSON. Not sure what is the problem here, you know how to do it properly.

Comment: Did you check the logs of your backend service?

Comment: the problem you are experiencing is caused because `[JSONFavs]` is one element array whereas `[{"id":21},{"id":16}]` is two element array

Comment: @pwolaq well but if I send `[{"id":21},{"id":16}]` works ok, while if I send `[JSONFavs]` doesn't. But they are the same (to me)

Comment: they aren't the same... if you want the same result after serialization you would have to use `"[" + JSONFavs + "]"`

Comment: why are you even doing serialization yourself, just pass an array as parameter...

Comment: @pwolaq can you give me your idea of the correct code? I'm having trouble fixing it even with `"[" + JSONFavs + "]"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the code below. What your code actually doing is assigning a Json STRING to $or property. But really needed is to assign array of items (as expected). Let me know if you have any questions

```
user_fav = "21,16";
//Dont need this
//var user_fav_to_array = "";
// New Variable to save array items
var arrayData =[];
var splitFav = user_fav.split(",");

for (var i = 0; i < splitFav.length; i++) {
   // don't need this
  //user_fav_to_array += JSON.stringify({ id: parseInt(splitFav[i]) }) + ',';
  // Just create a simple javascript object with id and put it into array at i index 
  arrayData[i]={ id: parseInt(splitFav[i]) }; 
}

//var JSONFavs = user_fav_to_array.substring(0, user_fav_to_array.length - 1);

// Then in Http Request filter, it should be just like this "$or": arrayData 
"filter": { "q": { "$or": arrayData } }
```

Answer (score 0):

This might have to deal with your variable - var user_fav_to_array = ""; 
You may want to change it to the following var user_fav_to_array = [];

Since it has the quotations it may be causing your variable to behave in a way that you don't want it to. Unless strings are treated as arrays in javascript.

Comment: Unfortunately behaves the same way

Comment: >.< Sorry for answering then. Also is JSONFavs just a string variable. Why did you put it within square brackets?

Comment: Ok. Well, the square brackets are part of the orginal code they gave ma at Backand.com

Comment: Remove the square brackets and your value for JSONFavs should mirror the value that you are looking for at the top. -> {"id":21},{"id":16}

Comment: I've verified that the output you are looking works by removing the square brackets. At that point, its possible that the value for JSONFavs isn't properly being passed when you are referencing it.

 "filter": { "q": { "$or": JSONFavs } }, // <-- HERE

Comment: Nope. If I do this: `"filter": { "q": { "$or": {"id":21},{"id":16} } },` it gives an error as it's not properly formatted

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138743/discussion-between-element-cr-and-mr-web).

Comment: I had to leave. Can you help me out here?

Comment: Sure, I will spend some time today and help you. Is all of the code found above sufficient for me to run in one node.js file?